# Determine if the given metric is bounded

Tags: metric-spaces, solution-verification

Is the Euclidean metric on $\mathbb{R}$ bounded?

I know that a metric $d$ on $X$ is bounded provided there exists $k \in \mathbb{R}$ so that $\forall x,y \in X, d(x,y)<k$.

Define $d: \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \to [0,\infty)$ by $d(x,y)=|x-y|$.

$(\mathbb{R},|\cdot|)$ is not bounded since $\nexists k \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $ \forall x,y \in \mathbb{R}, d(x,y)<k$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not an answer. Asserting that $d$ is bounded is to assert that, for some number $k>0$, you always have $d(x,y)<k$, and therefore, asserting that $d$ is not bounded is to assert that there is no number $k$ such that you always have $d(x,y)<k$. So, the assertion “$(\mathbb{R},|\cdot|)$ is not bounded since $\nexists k \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $ \forall x,y \in \mathbb{R}, d(x,y)<k$”, simply means “$(\mathbb{R},|\cdot|)$ is not bounded since it is not bounded”.

The space $(\Bbb R,|\cdot|)$ is not bounded because, for any $k>0$, $d(k,0)=|k-0|=k\geqslant k$. So, indeed, for any $k>0$, there are $x,y\in\Bbb R$ such that $d(x,y)\geqslant k$.